# Как установить несколько диапазонов в string.matches()?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Дело в том, что мне нужно что бы в строке были символы (a-z, A-Z, 0-9) и ничего более. Можно что бы каких то из них не было, главное, что бы не было других. Я использую этот код:

(password это EditText)

```
if (password.getText().toString().matches("[a-z]+")
    || password.getText().toString().matches("[A-Z]+")
    || password.getText().toString().matches("[0-9]+")) {
    //Пароль содержит правильные символы
} else {
    //Пароль содержит запрещённые символы
}
```

И как можно понять, когда учитывается один из этих диапазонов - всё хорошо (например: ABC, abc, 123 и т.д.), но когда символы из нескольких диапазонов (например: a123, AaBb123, A123 и т.д.) ни один из условий if не является верным.

Как все диапазоны вместить в match() без ИЛИ в ЕСЛИ?

Я пробовал `password.getText().toString().matches("[a-z][A-Z][0-9]+")`, но так оно вообще никогда не возвращает true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чуть-чуть по-другому объединять надо: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`